# Inequality of an expectation (here: perpetual put of an american option)

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, finance

for a given function $u(x):=\sup_{\tau \in T_{0,\infty}}E[(Ke^{-r\tau}-xe^{\sigma B_{\tau}-(\sigma^{2}\tau)/2})_{+}1_{\tau <\infty}]$ and  $x \in [0,\infty)$, K a positive real number, $(B_{t})$ a standard brownian, $T_{0,\infty}$ the set of all stopping times of the filtration of $(B_{t})_{t\geq 0}$, i want to show that $u(x)\geq (K-x)_{+}$.
In the book it is also said that for all $T>0$ it holds that $u(x)\geq E[(Ke^{-rT}-xe^{\sigma B_{T}-(\sigma^{2}T)/2)})_{+})]$ which implies $u(x)>0$. I could apply Jensen inequality here, but why do we get strictly $>0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the stopping time
$$
T = \inf\left\{
t : \sigma B_t > \left(\frac{\sigma^2}2 - r\right) t + C
\right\}
$$
It is finite with non zero probability.

Now define $\tau = \inf (T,1)$ (say), so that $\tau <\infty$. Hence 
$$
u(x) \ge E[(Ke^{-r\tau}-xe^{\sigma B_{\tau}-(\sigma^{2}\tau)/2})_{+}1_{\tau <\infty}]
\\
\ge P(\tau = T) \inf_{\omega: \tau\le 1}
 (Ke^{-r\tau}-xe^{\sigma B_{\tau}-(\sigma^{2}\tau)/2})_{+}
$$

Choose $C$ such as
$$
\inf_{\omega: \tau\le 1}
 (Ke^{-r\tau}-xe^{\sigma B_{\tau}-(\sigma^{2}\tau)/2})_{+}
>0
$$
and you will get $u(x)>0$.

Comment: I dont get it yet. Could you give me a hint? I should have also mentioned that the inequality holds for all T.

Comment: Choose $C$ such as the thing inside the $(.)_+$ is $>0$.

Comment: Well for expample i could choose $C:=log(K/(2x))$. Let $T$ me the first hitting time such that $T:=inf\{t:\sigma B_{t}+(r-\sigma^{2}/2)t = log(K/2)$. Then $u(x)\geq K/2e^{-rT}P( T is finite) >0$. Is this the way you mentioned it? But i have to prove it for all T >0. But mine is for a fixed T.

Comment: @zit the thing that matters is that $\sup_T$ is greater than what is obtained with any $T$, in particular the one you chose.

Comment: **According to the properties of the Brownian motion**, for every nonnegative $a$ and $b$, the probability that $B_t\lt at+b$ for every $t$ is $$1-e^{-ab},$$ hence, not zero when $a$ and $b$ are positive. Thus the result in your (accepted) answer is wrong for every $\sigma^2\gt2r$, $C\gt0$.

Comment: @Did I tried to fix it.

Comment: Now it works. A basic approach to solve this question is to note that $u(x)=0$ would imply $Ke^{-rT}-xe^{\sigma B_{T}-(\sigma^{2}T)/2)}\leqslant0$ with full probability. If $K\gt0$, this, in turn, would imply that $B_T\geqslant C$ almost surely for some finite $C$--which is absurd since the support of $B_T$ is unbounded from below. In the end, no stopping time seems to be involved, really.

Comment: @Did yes, I did not think at this kind of way. My approach is basically to try to find an explicit arbitrage in case of a mispriced security, which is always nice in practice :)