# Requirements for square integrable in the Doob-Meyer-Decomposition

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Hey i have given a non negative supermartingale $(J_{t})_{t\in[0,T]}$ of Class D. So there exists a Doob meyer decomposition $J_{t}=M_{t}-A_{t}$ where $M_{t}$ is uniformly integrable since $(J_{t})$ is of class D.  What requirements are needed to make $M_{t}$ square integrable? Since i want to apply martingale representation theorem. In my literature it is only said that: since $\{M_{t}: 0\leq t\leq T\}$ bounded integrable Martingale, it is square integrable. But i dont get this.

Comment: @ zit : why is $M_t$ bounded ? Best regards

Comment: You would be able to comment if the system recognized your previous account as yours. You should request a profile merge using [contact us](http://math.stackexchange.com/contact) link in the footer.

Comment: @ Raff: Maybe you could edit the question and add the content of the erased answer because my answer capitalizes on those assumptions sonow it lacks context to be understood. Best regards

Comment: OP: Sorry but what happens [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1038184/) (wrong answer accepted)?

Answer (score 0):

Ok in your case if got it right you have :

$Z_t=KS_t$ is dominating $X_t=e^{-rt}.\Phi(S_t)$, so as the [snell envelop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snell_envelope) $J_t$ is the "smallest supermaringale" dominating $X_t$. We have then (note $Z_t$ is a martingale on $[0,T]$ so it is also a supremartingale):

$$0\leq J_t\leq Z_t$$

Now we have using Itô's isometry that $\forall~ t\in [0,T]$ :

$$E[M^2_t]=E[\langle M\rangle_t]=E[\langle J\rangle_t]\leq E[\langle Z\rangle_t]<+\infty$$

#### Important Note

In your case $J_t$ is continuous so there is no jump part in the quadratic variation of this process. That's because under your assumptions, $X_t$ is regular in the sense of Karatzas and Shreve "Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus" definition 4.12 and by theorem 4.16 page 28 therein. In any case, I think that with a little bit of work you can figure out the same result in the jump case.

Comment: hello, could you please explain why $E[\langle J\rangle_t]\leq E[\langle Z\rangle_t]$? Does monotone property holds for quadratic variation? thanks a lot!